# Printing images/pages from web browser control

Tags: html, xml, google-maps, ms-access, vba

I have a form that pulls a static map from google maps in the web browser control (access 2010). The format of the image is .png. I need for this map image to print when I print the forms.

Can I somehow save the image (embed) with the record? Link an image control to url? Use XML to grab the file from the web and store in the database?

I'd rather not have to download/link to the images each time. I'm running out of ideas and the web is coming up empty.

Here is an example URL

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.386052,-122.083851&zoom=13&markers=37.386052,-122.083851&size=500x300&sensor=false

and this is the image link/xml

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.386052,-122.083851&amp;zoom=13&amp;markers=37.386052,-122.083851&amp;size=500x300&amp;sensor=false">
```

Thanks for any advice/tips!

Answer (score 1):

You could try downloading the image separately from the web browser control.  As access can't do this natively, have a look at [this](http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?163915-Download-a-file-over-HTTP-with-VBA)...

Comment: Thanks for the link(s). I am not familiar with XMLHTTP and I'm having a hard time connecting what the threads are talking about to how to download/store the image from the map link. So far I have the URL string for each map updating on current records, but I'm not sure how to use that to jump in to the XML portion. Thanks again.

Comment: I have managed to get something out of this.  The message box shows ?PNG and an arrow pointing right (?). here is the code I'm using.      objHttp.Open "GET", URL, False
objHttp.Send ("")

sourceHTML = objHttp.responseText
MsgBox sourceHTML